# computer slow to load web pages after uploading from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

All I know is since I went from snow leopard to mountain lion my macbook pro 2011 13" 2.3GHZ i 5 2410M is slow to load web pages.I am not an expert and that is all I can say.

Comment: Let's see if anyone has a ready answer. If not, we can help you edit your question to provide more details on what you've tried, what exactly you don't get. See the guides on [about] and [ask] if you don't get an answer and decide to edit your question. They are often helpful in refining / reframing your query.

Comment: Is it slow for all sites or only for some? If you have any extensions installed in Safari, can you disable them and try again?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, since your upgrade from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion, your system does not have enough RAM and this is causing it to run more slowly. Upgrading to more RAM should speed things up substantially.

Snow Leopard, when booted up to the Finder, takes approximately 2GB of RAM to run (that is if no apps are loaded and running). Mountain Lion, however, takes approximately 3.5GB of RAM in the same situation. When you start running apps, including Safari or any web browser, the amount of memory needed by the system goes considerably above these amounts. If your Mac has less than 4GB of physical RAM, then Mountain Lion is going to use the "swap file" to constantly write pages in and out of RAM and to the hard drive, which is going to slow down your system operation considerably.

If your system will support it, it will run much faster if you can upgrade with more RAM. [According to this chart](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1333MHz_SDRAM), your model of Mac can accommodate 8GB, 12GB or 16GB of RAM (confirm the exact model number to be sure), so you should consider upgrading.

Comment: It's a 2011 MacBook Pro => It has a least 4Gb. 4GB is enough for ML.

Comment: It is slow for many sites and not all the time.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: I have a '11 Mini with 8GB, and it idles at 6GB running Lion with just a few tabs open. The Lions are memory hungry.

Comment: I think it's more like : the more it has, the more it takes. I have no problem on my 2007 iMac w/ 4GB.

Comment: My 2011 macbook pro has 4GB RAM,but it is not enough, or there is another problem I don't know about.In any event the computer is often slow to load web pages.